# How to change jquery button icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button right this:

```
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right" id="RequestNewPwd">
           Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
        </button>
```

With a text and an icon. I'm trying to change the text and the icon like via javascript like this:

```
            $("#RequestNewPwd").button({
                label: "Sent",
                icons: {
                    primary: "m-icon-swapleft  m-icon-white",
                }
            })
```

But it does not work. I also tried:

```
$("#RequestNewPwd").text('Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>');
```

And it prints the html code like text. This works:

```
$("#RequestNewPwd").text('Submit');
```

But I need to show also the icon. Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: try changing `.text` to `.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are appending html,you need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$("#RequestNewPwd").html('Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.html()` to render the string into html elements.

Try,

```
$("#RequestNewPwd").html('Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>');
```